# Display ALL categories that a product belongs to in Magento

Tags: php, collections, magento, categories

I am conceptualizing a new Magento site which will have products that are included in several categories. What I am wondering is if I can display all categories a product is in on the product detail page. I know that it is possible to get *the* category, but is it possible to display a list of *all* categories which a product belongs to?

For example, a shirt may be included in the *Shirts* category, as well as in *Designers* and *Summer*. Ideally, I would like to be able to display the following:

> More from:
>
> Men > Shirts
>
> Men > Designers > Barnabé Hardy
>
> Men > Summer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will get you the data you are looking for such as the category's name, URL, etc:

```
$currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
                     ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

then just iterate over the collection e.g.

```
foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
  echo $cat->getName().' '.$cat->getUrl();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to display the full category path (with links at each stage) rather than only displaying the final category that a product belongs to?

Comment: That's pretty much it, yes. Having done a lot of searching for an answer to this, I found that Magento's definition of a breadcrumb differs from most of everyone elses - but yes, I would call it a breadcrumb.

Comment: Asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531702/magento-display-all-categories-on-product-view-page-with-parent-categories/9533005

Answer (score 1):

Simple.

```
$_categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection()
foreach ($_categories as $_category)
    //do something with $_category
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to display all categories related to the selected product in the product detail page.

```
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
           <?php foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id): ?>
           <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id) ?> 
< <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
```